# How do I move the logo/watermark and the info button on MGLMapView?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mglmapview

I'm wondering how do I move Mapbox's logo and the info button up a little on the map view. But anything I do doesn't seem to affect the map

[image]

--my first attempt to solve the problem

```
    let mapboxLogo = mapView.logoView
    mapView.logoView.isHidden = true
    let logoLeftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mapboxLogo, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mapView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8)
    let logoBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mapboxLogo, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mapView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 32)

    mapboxLogo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mapView.addConstraints([logoLeftConstraint, logoBottomConstraint])

    mapView.addSubview(mapboxLogo)
```

The result: 
[image]

Comment: Which version of the Mapbox iOS SDK are you using?

Comment: @jmkiley I believe I'm using the latest one 3.7.0. How do I check to make sure?

Comment: You should see console output in Xcode that suggests upgrading to the latest version if you are not on 3.7.0!

Comment: @jmkiley I update my mapbox to 3.7.0! Thanks!

Comment: I had to use constraints (under 4.0.0 SDK) as a workaround - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50932151/597231

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mapbox Maps SDK for iOS v3.7.0, you should be able to do this by a couple of ways:

1. Save the attribution button's action sheet. Then remove the original wordmark and attribution button, and place a new wordmark and attribution button in the desired location. Add the action sheet to the new attribution button.
2. Remove the original constraints and add your own.

You can find more suggestions and sample code [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/8003#issuecomment-278644190).

Comment: I came across that post before and it didn't help me. Maybe i'm not doing the constraints correctly? I'm not sure. I updated my post to include my attempt at this.