# Mapbox iOS move attribution Button

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm using the mapbox SDK and I need to show their logo watermark and their attribution mark. I can move them though, so I want to move the attribution button from the bottom right to bottom left next to the logo watermark.

I tried the following code but it did not work:

```
func mapViewWillStartLoadingMap(_ mapView: MGLMapView) {
    mapView.attributionButton.frame.offsetBy(dx: -200.0, dy: 0)
}
```

This is how it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
mapView.attributionButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
mapView.attributionButton.frame.size = CGSize(width:   self.mapView.frame.size.width - 120, height: 25)
```

you can also hide attribution Button as follow:

```
mapView.attributionButton.alpha = 0
```

Comment: I do not want to hide it. It's not allowed by mapbox. Just want to move it.

Comment: let me check @Mike

Answer (score 3):

I tried solutions like Harshal's but couldn't get that to work. Here's what worked for me (placing the attribution button near upper left). (Code added to `viewDidLoad()`)

```
self.view.addConstraints([
NSLayoutConstraint(item: mapView.attributionButton, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 25),
NSLayoutConstraint(item: mapView.attributionButton, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 25),
NSLayoutConstraint(item: mapView.attributionButton, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 72),
NSLayoutConstraint(item: mapView.attributionButton, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 24),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `scaleBarPosition` in `MGLMapView`

MapBox added the ability to do this in 4.3.0
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/commit/60ceac5efc3d77199f773f08400fe1d53d5a1b90